# MySql str_date with JSON object

Tags: mysql, json

I have following query

```
 SELECT  str_to_date(`created_at`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `created_at 
 FROM `categories`
```

If I run this query on PHPMyadmin it's working fine. 
and gives result

```
2014-09-15 11:59:55  ,  2014-09-15 12:40:12
```

I am getting Result in JSON Format 
OutPut is showing like this

```
2014-09-15T06:29:55.000Z
Mon Sep 15 2014 11:59:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want same output which is in MYSQL. I have datetime in MYSQL. Does anybody help me out

Comment: You are probably fetching the value and sending it as a date object. Send it as a string object instead.

Comment: I have no idea. can ypu tell me

Comment: Refer my answer and the SQL Fiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `created_at` 
FROM `categories`
```

`DATE_FORMAT` gives you date as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `created_at 
 FROM `categories`
```

Comment: Please refer comment on the post by Hitu

Answer (score 1):

**STR_TO_DATE**  converts the string to a date object.

When the date object is returned via JSON, the result is returned as you have specified.

To avoid this do either of the below,

1. Convert the Date again to String using `DATE_FORMAT` and send this string value to your JSON Output.
2. Since your records are already in the string format that you want, just take the value and pass the string to your json output

**Example: Approach 1**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE('18,05,2009','%d,%m,%Y') , '%Y-%m%d %H:%i%s');
```

Refer fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3285c/3